# jQuery - Combining multiple element selectors with :not - how

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a devil of a time getting two selectors to work *together* as well as do when I declared seperate.

My issue:

I want to close a menu when I move to *any* input OR anchor tag that is NOT contained with a certain element. When I explicitly code for both input and anchor, I get the behavior I need - BUT when I try to condense my code and combine them, it behaves weirdly and does not work as intended.

So, basically when a user focus's in an input field or anchor that is NOT a child of my selector I want to close a menu. When I use two sperate handlers, it works. I want to combine them.

I am trying to shorten this....

```
jQuery('#hdr input:not(#opt *)')
.focusin(function(event){
   setTimeout(function(){
       jQuery("#opt").hide()
   },100);
 });
jQuery('#hdr a:not(#opt *)')
.focusin(function(event){
   setTimeout(function(){
       jQuery("#opt").hide();
   },100);
 });
```

I've tried all of this into one line, to no avail:

```
jQuery('#hdr a input:not(#opt *)')
jQuery('#hdr a, #hdr input:not(#opt *)') <-- I expect this to work, but doesn't.
jQuery('#hdr a,input:not(#opt *)')
jQuery('#hdr *:not(#opt *)')
```

It seems to only work when I do a single arg like: #hdr a , or #hdr input  BUT when I try to combine them, no luck. I've searched high and low but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `not` method:

```
$('#hdr').find('a,input').not('#opt *')
```

Sometimes it's just better and more readable to use the methods instead of a huge selector string.

Comment: yeah - gosh I was "gonna" use find but not sure why I didn't event bother with it. Your way worked great! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

All the elements are child of  #opt and not selector ensure that #opt which is parent and all the elements or nodes in it are prevented from event handler. Like this in Fiddle:

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/gxYxL/)

Also The Method of @elclanrs works.

```
$("#hdr a:not(#opt), #hdr input:not(#opt)")
```